# Everything on my pages works fine on VScode's live server but not on local

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

When previewing my pages with a live server everything works fine.
but when I tried to open my index file from local it didn't show CSS or anything.
and when click on navigation that links to another page it shown "File not found"

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, please provide code with your question. Second of all, I had this once happening to me, I fixed it by changing (this is an example) `/CSS/style.css` to `./CSS/style.css`
So you basically put a dot in front of it. Please let me know if this helps.